# Java Regex xml parsing

Tags: java, xml, regex

I'm trying to find a tag from begin to end in xml and replace it with a blank. A sample xml is like this

```
<lins>
  <lin index="1"> ...<feature>Something</feature>... </lin>
  <lin index="2">...<feature>Something</feature>... </lin>
  <lin index="3">...<feature>Something</feature>....</lin>

  <lin index="1">...<feature>Icom</feature>... </lin>
  <lin index="2">...<feature>Icom</feature>... </lin>
<lins>
```

I need to remove `<lin>` to `</lin>` when ever I see  Icom in between

`<lin\s(.+?Icom.+?)+</lin>` is removing all lin items since it matches the first begin `<lin>` tag and the last lin end tag. Greatly appreciated if you can suggest a way to do this. Also I can not use xml parsers in my situation.

Comment: Please re-write what do you need to remove. It is not clear.

Comment: You do not have the choice to use some xml parser?

Comment: I'm trying to find a tag from begin to end in xml and replace it with a blank. A sample xml is in the question. In the above example I need to find and remove                                       <lin index="1">...   <feature>Icom</feature>... </lin>
  <lin index="2">...<feature>Icom</feature>... </lin> The rule is when ever I see Icom remove <lin> to </lin>
The regex I used is removing all lin tags. <lin (.+?Icom.+?)+</lin>

Comment: I my situation I can't use XML parsers

Comment: And what situation is that, virtually all platforms known to human have XML parsers.

Answer (score 4):

```
String result = subject.replaceAll("(?s)<lin\\b(?:(?!</lin).)*Icom(?:(?!</lin).)*</lin>", "");
```

should do this, unless you have `<lin>` tags nested into each other (or inside comments/strings).

**Explanation:**

```
<lin\b              # Match <lin (but not link or linen)
(?:                 # Match...
 (?!</lin)          # as long as we're not at a closing tag
 .                  # any character
)*                  # any number of times.
Icom                # Match Icom
(?:(?!</lin).)*     # (as above:) Match any character except closing tag
</lin>              # Match closing tag
```

Comment: it will not match if there's an inner <lin></lin> tag

Comment: @Ademiban: That's exactly what I wrote. Also, it *will* match, but it'll match an incorrect part of the string (which is probably even worse, which is why I wrote that `<lin>` tags must not be nested).

Comment: @user1110005 would be great to accept this answer and put a check next to it.

Answer (score 0):

you cant do it with regexp.
For this example:

```
<tag>
    <tag> something </tag>
</tag>

<tag>
</tag>
```

If you use `"<tag>(.*)</tag>"` regexp, your group will be this:

```
    <tag> something </tag>
</tag>

<tag>
```

and if you use `"<tag>(.*?)</tag>"` regexp, your group will be this:

```
    <tag> something
```

You should use something like stack to get the ending of started tag.

Comment: Your points are valid (about nested strings), however your examples are both wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add more groups to the regexp.

Add a group for the precondition to start checking for ex (

Then a group for the stuff inbetween, a group for Icom etc.

So off the top of my head my RegEx would look like:

```
(<lin\ index\=)(\w+Icom\w+)(\<\/lin>)
```

Note the escaping might be slightly off, but in essence you need more groups and some less eager matchers.